# Is it okay to call the plugin in each ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things">
    ...
    <script>$('.tooltip').tooltip();</script>
</div>
```

Of course I can't call `$('.tooltip').tooltip();` just after page loads, because when angularjs renders a new page, tooltip won't work until plugin is not called again. So, my question, is my approach horrible? Is there anything I could do differently?

Comment: Wrap tooltip as a directive. Yes, your approach is definitely not the Angular way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create directive and add this call after compile or link step.

Also check [ui.bootstrap.tooltip implementation](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tooltip/tooltip.js) and example of it's [usage](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip)

In case you decide to implement your own directive, most simple case going to be:

```
app.directive('tooltip', function (){
  return function(scope, elem) {
    elem.tooltip();
  }
});
```

Also in case you own plugin source code consider changing it from

```
$(selector).tooltip()
```

To 
    $(parent).tooltip(selector)

And use event delegation inside plugin ( i.e instead of

```
$(selector).on('mouseenter', handler)
```

your plugin will do

```
$(parent).on('mouseenter', selector, handler)
```

This way you can assign it once and create directive that can be applied to the top level node

```
<section enable-tooltip='.tooltip'>
   <p class='tooltip' ng-repeat='i in arr' tooltip='{{i.tooltip}}'></p>
</section>
```

So your directive would set events on top node 'section' and whatever changes you make to $scope.arr you won't need to on/off your handlers.

```
app.directive('enableTooltip', function (){
  return {
    scope: {
     selector:'@enableTooltip'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem) {
       elem.tooltip(scope.selector);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: how can I create a directive for this plugin?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should always create Directives instead of calling jQuery plugins directly.

It is best to create a native directive, however you can wrap most jQuery plugins in to a directive easily enough.

```
/* the pattern */
angular.module('myModule').directive('myWrappedPlugin', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            /* call your jquery plugin on the element */
            element.plugin();
        }
    };
});
```

To use your new directive, in html:

```
<!-- add the directive to your div -->
<!-- notice the name is converted to spinal-case -->
<div my-wrapped-plugin></div>
```

This basic pattern will work for most jQuery plugins. I'll refer you to the Directive documentation for more details: [Developer Guide / Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)